# Am I exceeding maximum limits for this plug?

Tags: maximum-ratings

I have a device which requires a 24V 1.2A adapter and it has a barrel jack for power input.
Now I need to use a 24V supply with [this pigtail DC Plug](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/dc-power-connectors/8840941) to power the device.

My question is:

The pigtail DC plug in the link has "Current rating 2 Amps max. at 16 V dc" and "Voltage Rating 16V".

In my case if I use this DC pigtail plug to power the 24V 1.2A device, am I exceeding the any limits? Should I look at current or power?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the thing is rated for only 16V then anything above 16V is too much.

You should be looking at all three, current, voltage, and power.

Now, we don't know why there is a 16V rating, so we don't know what happens if you use it for 24V, so we can't start guessing will it work in your case at 24V or not and what would happen if not.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/fc53/A700000007357162.pdf) carefully.

It gives the resistance between conductors as > 100 MΩ when measured at 500 V DC, and the dielectric withstand voltage as 500 V AC, which means peaks up to sqrt(2) * 500 = 707 V. It says the rating of the cable used is 300 V.

If you were a professional engineer, designing equipment for manufacture and sale, that had to meet various regulations depending on the ratings of the component parts, then you would not use it beyond the 16 V advertised rating.

If you were an amateur, making a one-off piece of equipment for your own personal use, you might make a different choice. In doing that, you would need to bear in mind that use of equipment beyond its ratings might invalidate insurance in the event of a claim.

Do not use this plug and socket as an on/off switch for the equipment. Disconnect it when carrying current only in an emergency. Be aware that the higher the voltage across opening contacts, the greater will be the erosion due to arcing.

Answer (score 0):

From a professional perspective: It says no more than 16V, so that's the limit. Exceed it and the component may fail in unexpected ways.

But.. practically speaking, that's an absurdly low voltage limit for a simple cable. I would not think twice about using it for 24V for a personal project.